# Book where character is describing aliens, turns out it's a Neanderthal describing humans

Tags: story-identification, books

My wife remembers reading a book (70's? English language) about a character who is describing the aliens around him, by the end of the book it turns out he's a Neanderthal and the aliens are humans.

Comment: *Hominids* by Robert J. Sawyer has modern humans encounter modern neanderthals, but it's not a sting reveal and the timeline is wrong...

Comment: Possibly The Inheritors by William Golding?

Comment: Ah yes, that's the one. She recognises the central character's name. Thanks for that

Answer (score 6):

As suggested by user starpilotsix and possibly confirmed by the OP in comments above, this may be William Golding's [*The Inheritors*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?31734) (1955).

Per the [Wikipedia plot summary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Inheritors_(Golding_novel)):

> This novel is an imaginative reconstruction of the life of a band of
> Neanderthals. It is written in such a way that the reader might assume
> the group to be modern Homo sapiens as they gesture and speak simply
> among themselves, and bury their dead with heartfelt, solemn rituals.
> They also have powerful sense impressions and feelings, and appear
> sometimes to share thoughts in a near-telepathic way. As the novel
> progresses it becomes more and more apparent that they live very
> simply, using their considerable mental abilities to connect to one
> another without extensive vocabulary or the kinds of memories that
> create culture. They have wide knowledge of food sources, mostly roots
> and vegetables. They chase hyenas from a larger beast's kill and eat
> meat, but they don't kill mammals themselves. They have a spiritual
> system centring on a female principle of bringing forth, but their
> lives are lived so much in the present that the reader realizes they
> are very different from us, living in something like an eternal
> present, or at most a present broken and shaped by seasons.
>
> One of the band, Lok, is a point of view character. He is the one we
> follow as one by one the adults of the band die or are killed, then
> the young are stolen by the "new people," a group of early modern
> humans. Lok and Fa, the remaining adults, are fascinated and repelled
> by the new people. They observe their actions and rituals with
> amazement, only slowly understanding that harm is meant by the sticks
> of the new people.
>
> The humans are portrayed as strange, godlike beings as the
> neanderthals witness their mastery of fire, Upper Palaeolithic
> weaponry and sailing.